# CreateJS : Get the ACTUAL bound area after the object has been rotated

Tags: javascript, html, web, createjs, 2d-games

I'm making an animation editor entirely with HTML and Javascript. For the Canvas manipulation operations I'm using CreateJS.

At this point, I want to render a small UI inside the canvas, that shows off what item is selected.

The problem starts when I rotate the Image, so far I know that I can get the Boundaries of a Bitmap after its transformation, but this operation gives me the data that I'm not Looking for.

The Code below sets the coordinates for the UI drawn in the canvas:

```
update : function(){

    //Big rectangle 
    this.ui[0].x = this.object.x;
    this.ui[0].y = this.object.y;
    this.ui[0].rotation = this.object.rotation;
    this.ui[0].scaleX = this.object.scaleX;
    this.ui[0].scaleY = this.object.scaleY;

    //North West rectangle coordinates
    this.ui[1].x = this.object.getTransformedBounds().x;
    this.ui[1].y = this.object.getTransformedBounds().y;

    //North East rectangle coordinates
    this.ui[2].x = this.object.getTransformedBounds().x + this.object.getTransformedBounds().width;
    this.ui[2].y = this.object.getTransformedBounds().y;

    //South West rectangle coordinates
    this.ui[3].x = this.object.getTransformedBounds().x;
    this.ui[3].y = this.object.getTransformedBounds().y + this.object.getTransformedBounds().height;

    //South East rectangle coordinates
    this.ui[4].x = this.object.getTransformedBounds().x + this.object.getTransformedBounds().width;
    this.ui[4].y = this.object.getTransformedBounds().y + this.object.getTransformedBounds().height;
}
```

The method getTransformedBounds() returns the whole rectangular area that the image occupies after it's transformation. Is there a way to get the Actual rectangular area that the object occupies in the canvas so I can achieve something like this:

http://postimg.org/image/5wr32wt7j/

and not this:

http://postimg.org/image/dqroob10f/

I'm kinda new with createJS so please bear with me.

Comment: Just as a side note, you should try to avoid calling methods repeatedly to get the same value. Calling it once and saving the result is a lot faster  and saves you a bunch of typing. `var bounds = this.object.getTransformedBounds()` and then `this.ui[4].x = bounds.x + bounds.width;`

Comment: Yeah you're right. I still can't get rid off of this weird habit. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getBounds()` instead of `getTransformedBounds()`. It returns the untransformed local bounds. Then just draw a rect in a Shape using those bounds, and transform the Shape to match the transformation of the "object".

Alternately, put both the "ui" and the "object" in a Container together, and apply the transformations to the Container instead of to the "object".